# Why will on average 64 signing privileges be assigned each block in Slasher algorithm?

Tags: proof-of-stake, slashings

In this post about Slasher algorithm: https://blog.ethereum.org/2014/01/15/slasher-a-punitive-proof-of-stake-algorithm, it says:

> At block K+1000, an address A with balance B gains a “signing privilege” if

```
sha256(n[K] + n[K+1] + ... + n[K+99] + A) < 2^256 * 64 * B / M.
```

> Essentially, an address has a chance of gaining a signing privilege proportional to the amount of money that it has, and on average 64 signing privileges will be assigned each block.

How does this inequality ensures that on average 64 signing privileges will be assigned each block?

Comment: I believe it works if you assume a uniform balance distribution, where with N validators, B / M is close to 1 / N.  P(sha256(...) < 2^256 * B / M) = B / M or 1 / N, so 1 validator is selected on average, and with  sha256(...) < 2^256 * 64 * B / M you get 64 validators selected on average.